# d_1 is metric and and which is not associated with any norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be vectorial space, $d:X^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$$d_1(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
 d(x,y) +1   & \mathrm{if\ } x\neq y\\
 0 & \mathrm{if\ } x=y.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that $d_1$ is metric and which is not associated with any norm.

Already show that it is metric, but I can not prove that not associated a any norm.
help me please.

Answer (score 1):

If $d_1$ were defined by a norm then

$$d_1 (ax,ay)=\|ax-ay\|=|a|\|x-y\|=|a|d_1(x,y), \forall a\in\mathbb{R}, x,y\in X.$$

But $$d_1(ax,ay)=d(ax,ay)+1$$ and $$|a|d_1(x,y)=|a|d(x,y)+|a|.$$

Comment: I thought I did something similar but I had this result $|a|d_1(x,y)=|a|d(x,y) +1$. HElp me whit definition, $|| x||=d_1(x,0)$ this definition is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\|x\|=d_1(x,0)$ and $\|x-y\|=d_1(x,y).$